# overwrite a csv file using vba

Tags: vba, ms-access, csv, ms-access-2007

There are a number of similar posts but nothing that does exactly what I want as simply as it needs to be for me to understand

I want to use Access 2007 VBA to open a csv file and replace the column headings row ie:

```
OldColumn1,OldColumn2

1,2
```

with

```
NewColumn1,NewColumn2

1,2
```

ie without disturbing the rump of data.

Then save and close.

I have tried this code, but it deletes my data:

```
Sub WriteFile()


  Dim OutputFileNum As Integer
  Dim PathName As String

  PathName = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
  OutputFileNum = FreeFile

  Open PathName & "\Test.csv" For Output Lock Write As #OutputFileNum

  Print #OutputFileNum, "NewCol1" & "," & "NewCol2"


  Close OutputFileNum

End Sub
```

Comment: Automate the routine with the Excel VBA reference instead, this will allow you to select and amend individual cells, e.g OldColumn1 may be in cell A1, this would be easier to work with.

Comment: Sorry Matt - could you elaborate? Presumably this would change the: "Open PathName & "\Test.csv" For Output Lock Write As #OutputFileNum" line.  What to?

Comment: @GERALDDUNN Please see my answer, you would no longer need to use the file handles.

Answer (score 1):

1. Import or link to the .csv so that you have the recordset in your Access 2007 databases.
2. Write a query with NewColumn[x] as an alias for OldColumn[x].
3. Write vba code to use TransferText functionality or make a macro to do the same to export your query as a .csv file (overwriting the original csv if you want/need).

Obviously, there are plenty of bonus things you could do to automate and reproduce this concept for any number or types of files.  But the above solution should work in an all MS Access environment.

Let me know if you would like details on any of these steps.

Answer (score 0):

Further to my earlier comment, please see the method which uses the Excel reference:

```
Public Sub EditCsv()

Dim xlApp As Object
dim xlWbk As Object
Dim xlWst As Object

    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set xlWbk = xlApp.Workbooks.Open ".../Test.csv" 'Amend this to your needs
    Set xlWst = xlWbk.Sheets(1)

    'This assumes the columns are at the beginning of the file
    xlWst.Range("A1") = "My New Column Name"
    xlWst.Range("B1") = "My New Second Column Name"

    xlWbk.Close -1 'Close and save the file here
    xlApp.Quit

    Set xlApp = Nothing
    Set xlWbk = Nothing
    Set xlWst = Nothing

End Sub
```